# Parsing CSV in golang with ISO-8859-1 encoding

Tags: csv, go

I have a csv file that has a row of headers and then several dozen lines. When I attempt to read it as a csv, it gets returned as 1 large slice. Why does it not get returned as separate rows?
Input looks like:

```
COL1,COL2
val1,val2
val1,val2
val1,val2
```

`object.Body` is a `ReadCloser`

```
lines, err := csv.NewReader(object.Body).ReadAll()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for _, line := range lines {
    log.Print(line)
}
```

Output is returned as

```
[COL1 COL2
val1,val2
val1,val2
val1,val2]
```

I would expect the return to be:

```
[
  [val1, val2],
  [val1, val2],
  [val1, val2],
]
```

Any ideas? Totally stumped on this one.

**Edit** I mistakenly forgot to add a comma in the header. This was only in the sample code, not the actual issue. Sorry for the confusion.

**Edit** I believe that this issue is due to an encoding of the csv file differently.

Comment: I copied and pasted [to the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SZSBdxpaUjP) and it works as expected.  What's different from actual code?

Comment: Issue must be the S3 side of things. I'm reading this information from a bucket and it must not be encoding it right. I thought it was at the parsing level but doesn't look like it.

Comment: S3 does not transform data.  Whatever you put in is what you get out.  Consider printing the first chunk of data with %q to see if data is what you expect it to be.

Comment: It is. I printed the whole thing out. It's a giant slice. I have a function that dumps to s3 and a function that reads from s3 and transforms it. At the point of trying to transform it, it doesn't understand it as a csv. I'm setting the content type to csv but if I download it, it is text.

Comment: If you're still curious, it's the body field of `GetObjectOutput` from aws's go s3 package.

Comment: What do you mean that it's a giant slice?  Can you given an example in the question? The problem is not in the code you have shown, so consider editing the question to include more code and context.

Comment: Can you add the output of `b := make([]byte, 128); io.ReadFull(object.Body, b); fmt.Println(hex.Dump(b))`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the first row in the sample you provided is not formed correctly. Shouldn't it be `COL1,COL2` instead?

I think the following code does what you want:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := bytes.NewBufferString(`COL1,COL2
val1,val2
val1,val2
val1,val2`)

    reader := csv.NewReader(data)
    reader.Read() // Skip header
    lines, err := reader.ReadAll()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(lines)
}
```

Comment: Hmm. If I read twice, it returns nothing because the first line reads everything.

Comment: Maybe it was because of the new line character of the source file. Try using "COL1,COL2\r\nval1,val2\r\nval1,val2\r\nval1,val2\r\n" as data instead?

Comment: The first call to `Read` should only discard the first line, not consuming the whole reader.

Comment: Have you tried using "COL1,COL2\r\nval1,val2\r\nval1,val2\r\nval1,val2\r\n" as the input string? I am running out of ideas if it still does not work as it worked on my machine :(

Comment: Sadly, this is all in a remote environment in lambda so it might be related to the content type of the file that's being read from. I can get it to work from a bytestring but simulating the whole application flow is tough.

Answer (score 0):

From [CSV RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180):

```
  3.  There maybe an optional header line appearing as the first line
   of the file with the same format as normal record lines.  This
   header will contain names corresponding to the fields in the file
   and should contain the same number of fields as the records in
   the rest of the file (the presence or absence of the header line
   should be indicated via the optional "header" parameter of this
   MIME type).  For example:

   field_name,field_name,field_name CRLF
   aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
   zzz,yyy,xxx CRLF
```

You're missing a comma in the header, the parser therefore thinks that the whole file is one column wide.