# CSV Encoding Broken when Downloading from S3

Tags: csv, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to download a CSV file from S3 using golang's SDK but it comes out encoded wrongly and is interpreted as one slice.

```
input := &s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket:                  aws.String(bucket),
    Key:                     aws.String(key),
    ResponseContentType:     aws.String("text/csv"),
    ResponseContentEncoding: aws.String("utf-8"),
}

object, err := s3.New(s).GetObject(input)
if err != nil {
    var obj s3.GetObjectOutput

    return &obj, err
}

defer object.Body.Close()

lines, err := csv.NewReader(object.Body).ReadAll()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

log.Printf("%q", lines[0])


// returns ["\ufeffH1" "H2\r" "field1" "field2\r" "field1" field2\r00602"]
```

I'm guessing this is incorrect character encoding. Problem is that I'm not clear what encoding that it is. When I'm putting the file, I'm specifying csv.

I would have expected to see `[][]string`:

```
[
  [],
  []
]
```

Any advice?

**Approach 2**

```
buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
buffer.ReadFrom(object.Body)

str := buffer.String()

lines, err := csv.NewReader(strings.NewReader(str)).ReadAll()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

log.Printf("length: %v", len(lines))
// still one line
```

**Approach 3**

My new approach is going to be manually removing byte sequences that are problematic. This is pretty terrible. Godocs on this need work.

This is closer but now I have to split out on new lines then again on commas.

**Edit**
When I print out the bytes it looks like:
`"\ufeffH1,H2\r,field1,field2\r`

I have tried using the following encodings:

`utf-8`, `iso-8859-1`, `iso-8859-1:utf-8`

Comment: try `csv.NewReader(strings.NewReader(object.Body))`

Comment: hmm, I get a compile error: `cannot use object.Body (type io.ReadCloser) as type string in argument to strings.NewReader`

Comment: 1) S3 returns the object contents as is. The ResponseContentEncoding and ResponseContentType options set the response headers, the options do not specify any transformation of the data. 2)  It looks like the response starts with a [byte order mark](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark).  You will need to skip over that. 3) It looks like lines are separated by \r.  To aid debugging, please dump raw body data as suggested to you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53245917/parsing-csv-in-golang-with-iso-8859-1-encoding#comment93378249_53245917).

Comment: @ThunderCat updated. It's a string with the weird encodings.

Comment: Thank you for showing the actual data as was asked in comments on your previous question. The file uploaded to S3 is not encoded per the [CSV Encoding RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180).  Specifically, the file uses CR to separate lines instead of CRLF. Because the [encoding/csv](https://godoc.org/encoding/csv) reader handles LF separators, the easiest workaround is to translate CR to LF in the input.  Also, the file contains a byte order mark. Skip over those two bytes before decoding.

Comment: OK that makes sense. Thank you.